# Gradle - unzipping latest version of dependency

Tags: gradle

I have the following gradle task that unzips a dependency which has been downloaded to `tmp`.

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
   def zipFile = file('tmp/dist-1.0.1.zip')
   def outDir = file("unpacked/dist")

   from zipTree(zipFile)
   into outDir
}
```

However, I'm looking to download the latest version of the dependency rather than a specific version (i.e. the script will download `dist-1.0.+`).

Is there a way that I can unzip the dependency, no matter which version of the dependency has been downloaded?

Comment: To find out what the latest version of a dependency is, at runtime, it is probably best to use gradle's dependency resolution mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a new configuration, so as not to pollute existing project configurations:

```
configurations{
    download 
}
```

Add a dependency into the declared configuration, with version wildcard as desired. Just using `+` for version will get you the latest version available in the declared repositories:

```
dependencies{
    download `foo:bar:+`
}
```

Unzip the resolved dependency:

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    def zipPath = project.configurations.download.find {it.name.startsWith('bar') }
    def zipFile = file(zipPath)
    def outDir = file("unpacked/dist")

    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into outDir
}
```

Note: it is generally a bad practice to use wildcard in project dependency versions. This makes the build non-deterministic - if a newer version of a dependency with breaking changes is published to the source repo, it could break your build.